# Ng-bootstrap Carousel refuses to show Images

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm upgrading from an old version of bootstrap (0.13.4 & 0.14.1) to a new version of it.

The old slider worked just fine, but doesn't show any images anymore, when the new file is in use.
This makes sense, due to the fact, that the syntax of bootstrap has changed since that version.

This is the Original Code:

```
<div class="ecp-carousel">
    <uib-carousel interval="5000" no-wrap="false">
        <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in e.slides " active="slide.active">
            <div class="slidcontainer clearfix">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            </div>
        </uib-slide>
    </uib-carousel>
</div>
```

This is the code I came up with:

```
<div class="ecp-carousel">
    <div uib-carousel interval="5000" no-wrap="false" class="carousel-indicators">
        <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in e.slides" index="slide.id" class="item">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="slidcontainer clearfix">           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, it doesn't display any images unless, you manually go to the Inspector in your Browser(Ctrl + Shift + I ) inspect the Code and add the class "active" by hand, to that one image, that should be displayed.
But the controls still won't work. And if you do this with multiple Images, they'll all be displayed below each other.

This is the documentation of the slider:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you guys (and girls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that the index was not specified. The carousel activated multiple slides at it's own discretion and therefore an error occured (that it couldn't handle), because it wasn't shure of which slide to display. (Because there were multiple active slides)
So the carousel broke an nothing was displayed.

This is the final view:

```
    <div class="ecp-carousel">
        <div uib-carousel interval="5000" no-wrap="false">
            <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in e.slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id" class="item">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Error was in the Controller, not in the view.

Answer (score 1):

`active` is a *required* attribute and it has to be specified otherwise [the angular error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign) will be thrown. According to [the documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/):

> `active`  (Default: Index of first slide) - Index of current active
>   slide.

In addition `carousel-indicators` class should be omitted from `uib-carousel` directive, it is used for carousel indicators.

Fixed carousel:

```
<div class="ecp-carousel">
        <div uib-carousel active="0" interval="5000" no-wrap="false">
            <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in e.slides" index="slide.id" class="item">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                <div class="slidcontainer clearfix">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Example**

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  $scope.active = 0;
  $scope.e = {};
  var slides = $scope.e.slides = [];
  var currIndex = 0;

  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
      image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['Nice cat','Awesome photograph','Cute kitten','Home animals'][slides.length % 4],
      id: currIndex++
    });
  };

  

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $scope.addSlide();
  }

  
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">

        
        <div class="ecp-carousel">
    <div uib-carousel active="0" interval="5000" no-wrap="false">
        <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in e.slides" index="slide.id" class="item">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="slidcontainer clearfix">           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer.
However it did not solve the Problem for me. It still won't show the image (allthough it's there) and it't doesn't slide either.
The only thing, that worked for me, was, that it doesn't redirect to another page anymore.

@VladimGremyachev

Comment: @VladimGremyachev, thank you, but the Problem has been solved.